# How to resolve this segmentation fault in my program with the following Address Sanitizer output?

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, gdb, g++, sanitizer

This question is a sequel of my previous question and the current status is that I have obtained the output of address sanitizer -- suggested by @Employed Russian -- which is given below. This is my first time that I have used address sanitizer so I beg your pardon for being naive.

```
==2596== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff89d67fd0 at pc 0x401f21 bp 0x7fff89d67d00 sp 0x7fff89d67cf8
READ of size 4 at 0x7fff89d67fd0 thread T0
    #0 0x401f20 (/home/ubuntu/tp+0x401f20)
    #1 0x405bac (/home/ubuntu/tp+0x405bac)
    #2 0x406d40 (/home/ubuntu/tp+0x406d40)
    #3 0x7fb5a7d6fec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21ec4)
    #4 0x401278 (/home/ubuntu/tp+0x401278)
Address 0x7fff89d67fd0 is located at offset 320 in frame <TMV_multiplication> of T0's stack:
This frame has 13 object(s):
   [32, 60) 'A11_Upper_matrix'
   [96, 124) 'A_Upper_matrix'
   [160, 192) 'A11_Lower_matrix'
   [224, 256) 'A_Lower_matrix'
   [288, 320) 'VecA'
   [352, 384) 'VecB'
   [416, 448) 'VecC'
   [480, 536) 'result_A_Upper'
   [576, 632) 'result_C_Upper'
   [672, 732) 'matrix_A21'
   [768, 832) 'result_A_Lower'
   [864, 928) 'result_B'
   [960, 1024) 'result_C_Lower'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
  (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
0x1000713a4fa0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1
0x1000713a4fb0: 00 00 f4 f4 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 04 f2 f2 f2 f2
0x1000713a4fc0: 00 00 00 00 f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x1000713a4fd0: 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 00 00 00 04 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00
0x1000713a4fe0: 00 04 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00
=>0x1000713a4ff0: 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00[f2]f2 f2 f2 00 00
0x1000713a5000: 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00
0x1000713a5010: 00 00 00 00 00 f4 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x1000713a5020: 00 f4 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 f2 f2
0x1000713a5030: f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00
0x1000713a5040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
   Addressable:           00
   Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
   Heap left redzone:     fa
   Heap righ redzone:     fb
   Freed Heap region:     fd
   Stack left redzone:    f1
   Stack mid redzone:     f2
   Stack right redzone:   f3
   Stack partial redzone: f4
   Stack after return:    f5
   Stack use after scope: f8
   Global redzone:        f9
   Global init order:     f6
   Poisoned by user:      f7
   ASan internal:         fe
==2596== ABORTING
```

As pointed out earlier by @Employed Russian that most probably the problem is with the stack. Now, how to resolving this stack problem? Because these are over my head.

Comment: As someone who's always hated GDB could you show us the code?

Comment: Can you indicate which line causes the segfault?  Where do you find X[16] = Y[0] and so on?

Comment: @Jerry when the execution ends in func(X,Y,Z) i.e. after the last closing brace } of func(X,Y,Z). Using the print command in gdb I found X[16]=Y[0] and so on.

Comment: @JonathanMee If I have understood you correctly, do you mean the main()?

Comment: @user110219 Sorry that made no sense, I apologize. Let me try again: Is this your code, or are you debugging someone else's stuff? Are you sure it fails within the body of `func`? There are called functions: `LT`, `UT`, and `TW`. It would be difficult to say what this function is doing without knowlege of those functions.

Comment: @JonathanMee this is my own code and all those functions are coded by me. Based on the line-by-line debugging that I do, I am sure that it is func() that ends with error. In case if I find something new, then I will update the post.

Comment: @user110219 When you say "I am sure that it is `func()` that ends with error [sic]" What line fails? What is the error, is it an out of bounds index?

Comment: @JonathanMee If you read the second paragraph of the post that starts with "What is really bothering me?", then you get both the line and error.

Comment: By that you mean: "0x000000008304ed6a in ?? ()" Heh, Perhaps you could relate that to a line of actual code for me?

Comment: Your code can ends with an error in `func()` also if the problem (an access outside the limit of an array?) is in another point of the program (`UT()`? `LT()`?). You shoul'd show us a full (with a `main()`, `UT()`, `LT()`) and segmentation-faulting example.

Comment: @JonathanMee I also don't know what does that error mean and how to get rid of it. The program is about 300 lines of code and the func() ends on line 255. So, using the "next" command in gdb on line 255 I get the above error. On the other hand, the next command runs smoothly through other statements of func()

Comment: @user110219 For debugging questions you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The first step toward that is identifying *where* the failure occurs. There's no doubt that GDB is difficult to use, an IDE may be able to assist you in this, but for http://www.stackoverflow.com to be of help to you you need to get this into an MCVE.

Comment: You find that X[16] = Y[0] ... X[47] = Z[15] because (I suppose) X, Y and Z are sequentially memorized; so the first place after the last element (X[15]) of X is occupied by the first element of Y (Y[0]). And so on. Not strange at all.

Comment: Need to see the code for `TW`. Good chance that it (or something it calls) is writing beyond the end of the `m_A21` array, which will corrupt `func`'s stack frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have three unsigned int arrays `X[16], Y[16], Z[16]` in the `main`...
>   `X[32]=Z[0]`

You can stop *right here*.

The valid indices for accessing `X` are 0 through 15. When you access `X[16]` (and beyond) you are invoking undefined behavior (anything can happen).

I *think* you didn't actually mean that you assign to `X[32]`. What you probably meant is that `&X[32]` is the same as `&Z[0]`. If that's the case, there is nothing particularly interesting about it: the arrays are laid out in memory one after the other.

> `0x000000008304ed6a in ?? ()`

This usually means stack corruption (something overwrote return address, and you returned into the middle of nowhere). Assuming `X` is a *local* array, writing to it out of bounds is exceedingly likely to cause just such corruption.

An easy way to find such stack corruption is to use Address Sanitizer (available for Clang and GCC).

**Update:**

The Address Sanitizer error is telling you that

- In `TMV_multiplication()`, you have a local array `VecA` of 32 bytes (probably `int VecA[8];`) and
- You access (read) that array out of bounds (trying to access offset 320, which is just past the end of that array).

This error *is not* the cause of your crash. You should fix it, and rerun again. There are more bugs after this one. Once you fix them all, your program will stop crashing.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I am not interested in how the compiler manages the array in memory. I have got the output of Address Sanitizer for my program and according to my naive interpretation it shows stack errors that are stack left redzone, stack right redzone, stack mid redzone, and stack partial redzone. The number of stack mid redzone is highest. So what to do next?

Comment: "what to do next?" -- edit your question and show Address Sanitizer output.

Comment: I beg your pardon for being late and the question has been amended.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the output of address sanitizer but why you have deleted the source?

Anyway, If I'm not wrong, the output says to you that there is an access in `VecA[8]`, that is out of range.

Comment: I have deleted the source code because it makes the post very lengthy. So, how did you find from address sanitizer that there is out of range access in VecA[8]?

Comment: I am sure that I am not doing out of range access in my source code. So where can things go wrong?

Comment: I think it'a an access in `VecA[8]` because I read `READ of size 4 at 0x7fff89d67fd0`, then `Address 0x7fff89d67fd0 is located at offset 320 in frame [...]` and `[288, 320) 'VecA'`. So `VecA[0]` is in in frame position 288, `VecA[1]` in position 292, [...], `VecA[8]` in position 320. I don't know what is wrong in your code and you should present your full code if you want that we try to respond to your question.